# Twisted callLater passing in a class instance

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

When I do

```
reactor.callLater(5, my_func, self)
```

The object which is passed to my_func is not the self I called callLater from. They have different addresses (as verified by print(self) and print(my_arg)).

What am I missing here? Is there any way for
    my_func(classObj)
to see the actual instance sent in?

My intention is to set up a delayed check for whether a certain property of self ever got set. I can do things differently (and actually already have) but something about the situation doesn't smell right, so I thought I'd clarify for future application.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed something doesn't smell right.  The following code works as expected and the variables passed in have the same address.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

def verify(obj):
    """ Check whether the value variable has been set or not.
    """
    if obj.value:
        print('Value was set')
    else:
        print('Value was not set')

def compare(A, B):
    """ Compare obj A == B
    """
    if A == B:
        print('Objects are the same')
    else:
        print('Objects are not the same')


class txClass:
    value = None

    def verify(self):
        reactor.callLater(5, verify, self)

    def compare(self, obj):
        reactor.callLater(5, compare, self, obj)


A = txClass()
A.verify()          # verify obj.value is set
A.value = 'test'

B = txClass()
A.compare(A)        # compare same obj
A.compare(B)        # compare diff obj
reactor.run()
```